# can not copy big file to usb device

Tags: linux, usb, mount, cp

I mount usb device like this:

> sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb

and then copy a big file which about 1Gb to the device:

> sudo cp ~/big_file /media/usb

Ordinary, if I copy a big file to usb, the command should run a few minutes. But it finish quickly.

And then I check the file in usb:

> md5sum /media/usb/bigfile

It is same as origin file. Then I umount the usb and it run a long time:

> sudo umount /media/usb

When I remount the usb device and check the file with md5sum again, the file in usb is different from origin file.

I am sure the device is ok because I can copy the file success in Windows, so what is the problem of my system?

Comment: 1. You can monitor read and writes to the device to see when the actual transfer finishes. 
2. try to flush the buffers before unmounting. use command `sync` couple of times.

Comment: @mnmnc I run `iostat` and found that it was still writing data to usb device, although `cp` was finish. Why `cp` was finish before the data was copied to usb device completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy a big file the system can spend a huge time to execute it, so it's running in background.

Be sure the file copy is complete using `# lsof /media/usb/bigfile`

You can request a sync of file copy with `# sync`

And you can umount your device the lazy way: `# umount -l /media/usb`

From umount(8):

> -l Lazy unmount. Detach the filesystem from the filesystem  hierarchy now, and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.  (Requires kernel 2.4.11 or later.)